# Pywinauto, No Text in TtsGridEditBox (Delphi XE2 GUI created App being tested)

Tags: delphi-xe2, pywinauto

Try as I might..

I can't get the displayed text using pywinauto from an in house application tool (Eurotherm's iTools), written with Delphi. I have written a large amount of Python test code (infrustructure) using pywinauto. I plotted the browser x,y elements using a text file for the expanded and indented structure coordinates because there is no text within the browser '`TUivOPCTreeView`' frame.

I managed to select `TtsGridEditBox` via `DoubleClickInput` and highlight it with `DrawOutline()`. All efforts `.UserData()`, `.Texts()`, `.WindowText()`, looping through children filtering lamda's and a multitude of crashing commands give text of ''. I think my only option is to copy the text as it seems it can't be read.

I managed to delete `(.TypeKeys("{HOME}{DELETE}{DELETE}{DELETE}{DELETE}{DELETE}")` and enter a different value `(.TypeKeys(' + var + '"{ENTER}"))`.

Is there a way to issue: home, select, end, copy with `.TypeKeys` or anything else?

```
Control Identifiers:
TtsGridEditBox - ''   (L680, T498, R776, B512)
        '49' 'TtsGridEditBox' ()
Read WindowText from valueNum20 is {u'UserData': 0, u'Style': 1409286144, u'ControlCount':
 0, u'ClientRects': [<RECT L0, T0, R96, B14>], u'IsEnabled': True, u'Fonts': [<LOGFONTW 'M
S Shell Dlg' -11>], u'FriendlyClassName': u'TtsGridEditBox', u'IsUnicode': True, u'Texts':
 [''], u'ContextHelpID': 0, u'ExStyle': 0, u'IsVisible': True, u'ControlID': 2100226, u'Me
nuItems': [], u'Class': u'TtsGridEditBox', u'Rectangle': <RECT L680, T498, R776, B512>}
```

> The GUI is written in Delphi XE2 (2012) v16.0.4504.48754 with plugins
>   TeeChart 2012, VirtualTreeViewV5.1.3 and TopGrid 2_20.

Has pywinauto ever been run on non win32 written apps, such as Delphi? 
Does this ring any bells with anyone?

I'm convinced that the Delphi written GUI displays but strangely masks the text for any automated tools.

Much, frustrated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Delphi VCL is Win32. Reading edit controls should be routine. What class is the control.

Comment: TCustomTreeView is the class that TUivOPCTreeView is derived. There are masses of them. I use AutoIt Window info tool that gives me Class and coords. Could it be 'class CVersadacSecurityManagerDlg : public CDialogEx' that is masking text?

Comment: If you wrote this software in house surely you know what it is. I'm sure I can't guess.

Comment: I didn't write it. I'm trying to automate using it..

Comment: You did write it according to the question. In house tool you said. And you are using UI Automation.

Comment: Ok. Changed original to make clearer..

Comment: I know guys who automated Delphi XE apps with pywinauto, but Delphi grids are really painful for GUI automation (both Win32 API and UI Automation). Anyway workarounds like `tree.type_keys('{DOWN 2}{RIGHT}^c')` are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Could find [an implementation of UI Automation patterns for some Delphi controls](https://github.com/jhc-systems/DelphiUIAutomation/tree/master/controls) including StringGrid.

[This parent project "DelphiUIAutomation"](https://github.com/jhc-systems/DelphiUIAutomation) can help you using pywinauto with these enhanced controls. Or you may choose Delphi itself for your test code.

Comment: I gave up and left the company. They wern't interested in automating their app and was asking me to manually test everything. I was convinced they were using a security masking class globally. Delphi is nasty anyway!

Comment: OK, let me wish you more testable/automatable products in the future. :)